# Signature verification failure - RTM Token

Tags: agora.io

https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/Video-Calling/tree/master/OpenDuo-Web

I have set up as per the steps listed above.

I have an RTM Token Generator and am placing the generated token in this._token = '' as listed in the code sample below.

Receving an error as follows.
RTM:ERROR Error Code 5. Signature verification failed

```
export default class RTMClient {
constructor () {
this._client = AgoraRTM.createInstance(appID)
this._uid = ''
this._token = '' // token placed here after generating 
this._invitation = null
this._remoteInvitation = null
this.eventBus = new EventEmitter() 

//This status is used to control whether the phone can be accessed
//The 'onLine' is ok.
this.status = 'offLine' //onLine, offLine, calling, meeting

this.peerInvitation()
}
```

Comment: Hey! can you please provide the stack trace?

Comment: Generating token of that particular uid. The random number that you generating.

Answer (score 0):

This error may come when you are not generating a token from the UID you are creating for the rtc and RTM package.
To resolve this you need to generate the token based on the uuid(random number).